# Expo fetch show inverse results

Tags: fetch, expo

my team and I are working on the fetch method for Expo and it looks something like this.

```
export function getCalendarEvents() {
  return fetch('http://50520dbf.ngrok.io/api/v1/events/date/')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {

      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        dataSource: responseJson,
      }, function () {

      });

    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error(error);
    });
}
```

And based on this method, it returns us the values below in this order

```
[ 
   { 
      "feedbackLogId":4,
      "time":"3 Weeks Ago",
      "recipient":"10060878",
      "type":"Compliment",
      "sender":"10060878",
      "imageUrl":"",
      "name":"AUNG THU"
   },
   { 
      "feedbackLogId":5,
      "time":"1 Weeks Ago",
      "recipient":"10060878",
      "type":"Compliment",
      "sender":"10060878",
      "imageUrl":"",
      "name":"JUN HAO 3"
   }
]
```

Is there a way where I can inverse the order of the fetch such that it returns in the other way around like this?

```
[ 
   { 
      "feedbackLogId":5,
      "time":"1 Weeks Ago",
      "recipient":"10060878",
      "type":"Compliment",
      "sender":"10059046",
      "imageUrl":"",
      "name":"JUN HAO 3"
   },
   { 
      "feedbackLogId":4,
      "time":"3 Weeks Ago",
      "recipient":"10060273",
      "type":"Compliment",
      "sender":"10059046",
      "imageUrl":"",
      "name":"AUNG THU"
   }
]
```

Thanks for the help and cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do that by explicitly reversing the array response. The `reverse` function form [Lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/#reverse) can help you achieve just that.

Your code will become.

```
import { reverse } from 'lodash';
...
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        dataSource: reverse(responseJson),
      }, function () {
...
```